# Issue Installing Entity Framework 7 RC1

Tags: .net, entity-framework, visual-studio, nuget, .net-4.5.2

I 'm trying to install EF7 rc1 to an existing project:

> PM> Install-Package EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer –Pre

but I get the following error:

> Install failed. Rolling back...
>   Package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 1.0.0-rc1-final' does not exist in project 'XYZ'

And at in the end of the trace I get this other message:

> Install-Package : Failed to add reference to 'System.Collections.Concurrent'. Please make sure that it is in the Global Assembly Cache.

I googled and can see that Concurrent collection have been in dotnet for a while but I have not such assembly in my dev box.

**Update:**

After querying the gac with `gacutil` I realize that indeed the assembly is present:

The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:

> System.Collections.Concurrent, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL

Comment: `I have not such assembly in my dev box` What that is mean? How do you check?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan it is not present in the list of assemblies if I want to set a reference to it. I even used gacutil command I cannot see that assembly in my gac.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, I made a typo while quering the gac. Yes, I have version 4.0 present.

Comment: What is your project's target framework version?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan 4.5.2

Comment: HOW IS THIS STILL A PROBLEM!!! ???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After getting this error, I was able to install EF7 RC1 to my project by removing references to my other projects, after that I was able to install EF7 RC1 succesfully to the project where I needed it, and then added references back, after which solution started to compile (and at least some basic EF functionality starts to work). Probably a glitch of nuget/dnu.

Comment: This was the way to go in my case too.

Comment: Same issue, however I only got it working after deleting references to other NuGet packages (StructureMap, Caliburn Micro, MahApps Metro, MaterialDesignInXaml, Dragablz, MediatR, FluentValidation).

Answer (score 11):

As I had no `System.Collections.Concurrent` assembly in GAC, I installed `System.Collections.Concurrent` NuGet package:

```
Install-Package System.Collections.Concurrent
```

Then manually added reference to `packages\System.Collections.Concurrent.4.0.10\lib\dotnet\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll` (because net46 folder was empty).

After that, installation of `EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer` finished with no errors.

Comment: I had the exact same problem and this is what fixed my issue.  The accepted answer did not work in my case.  I had a 4.6 WPF project which would not install the Nuget package (same errors as the OP).  Interestingly, there was no 4.6 dll for System.Collections.Concurrent so I had to use the version in the dotnet folder instead.just like this solution.  They are not providing a 4.5/4.6 version of the assembly so NuGet is breaking I think.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had to remove xUnit nuget packages. After removing those references Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 1.0.0-rc1-final installs correctly. Afterward I added xUnit back without any issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting this now (as in April 2016) then these answers may be out of date. I'm installing EF7 for the first time, but what I found was this :

- I installed `EntityFramework.SqlServer` first thinking this was the most 'top level' package I need
- I tried to install `EntityFramework.Commands` and got the stupid 'collections' error shown above

I looked carefully at the versions.

- SqlServer was still Beta 8
- Commands was RC1

So I went to 'Manage nuget packages' for the project and updated everything shown under updates.
I actually had to do this twice.

This then brought the EF7 core stuff up to RC1

I was then able to install `EntityFramework.Commands` without issue.

---

## BUT this is not what you want to do?

[Why?](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/85)
Because they renamed `EntityFramework.SqlServer` package to `EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer`

So you actually want to uninstall `*.SqlServer` and install `*.MicrosoftSqlServer`

That explains why there was no RC1 version.

Answer (score 1):

This is a PITA, but using `.Net v4.5.2` my workaround for getting `EntityFramework.Core -pre` installed is:

1. Create a clean class library with no NuGets installed.
2. `install-package entityframework.core -pre`
3. Copy the content of `packages.config` but **don't include** the line representing `EntityFramework.Core`
4. Include the lines in the `packages.config` that you are installing it to.
5. `update-package -reinstall -projectName YourProjectNameFromStep4`
6. `install-package EntityFramework.Core -pre`

**NOTE!** If **step 5** fails, you can have to do:

1. `install-package System.Collections.Concurrent -version 4.0.0 -projectName YourProjectNameFromStep4`
2. `install-package System.Runtime -version 4.0.0 -projectName YourProjectNameFromStep4`

These can then be removed after the install from **step 6** succeeds:

1. `uninstall-package System.Collections.Concurrent -projectName YourProjectNameFromStep4`
2. `uninstall-package System.Runtime -projectName YourProjectNameFromStep4`

After restart of Visual Studio it might say "Can not find `System.Collections.Concurrent` but closing your eyes for this seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. I uninstalled ef7-beta8 and its dependences and reinstalled ef7... Problem solved, so it seems there is a bug on the update logic or in nuget itself, don't know for sure.

Comment: Thanks Yanko, this is not the problem in my case. I previously had 6.x and uninstalled successfully.

Comment: Ah ok :-), But I think there is something wrong there, because I saw the same error messages (to the letter) when I upgraded from beta8 to rc1.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I created a new project, installed EF 7, added previous source files manually and it worked.